# How can i output the response of PHP shell_exec into a HTML table?

Tags: php, html, arrays

I have a PHP shell_exec command that outputs the following:

```
Cats
3
Dogs
9
Fish
2
```

Every second line is a number, that corresponds to the name of the animal on previous line, i would like the output in a HTML table for example:

```
HTML TABLE
------------
| Cats | 3 |
| Dogs | 9 |
| Fish | 2 |
------------
```

I think i need to create an array, but i am not sure how to align the animal name and number onto the same line. At the moment i have this:

```
<?php
    $array1 = array();
    exec( "Command", $Output );

?>
<html>


<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Animal</th>
    <th>Number</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>*</td>
    <td>*</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>*</td>
    <td>*</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>*</td>
    <td>*</td>
  </tr>

  </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

How can i put this into a HTML Table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert it to array with [array-chunk](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php) after using `explode` to convert to array.

```
$str = 'Cats
3
Dogs
9
Fish
2';

$arr = explode(PHP_EOL, $str); //break each line
$arr = array_chunk($arr,2); // group each pair
foreach($arr as $e)
    $res[$e[0]] = $e[1]; // group each pair as key and value
print_r($res);
```

This will output:

```
Array
(
    [Cats] => 3
    [Dogs] => 9
    [Fish] => 2
)
```

You can now use this more easily to display by looping with `foreach($res as $animal => $number)`

Your HTML should be:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Animal</th>
    <th>Number</th>
  </tr>
<?php foreach($res as $animal => $number)
    echo '<tr><td>'. $animal . '</td><td>' . $number . '</td></tr>'; ?>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks, How would i enter this into the HTML table?

Comment: @jonnyb You can add PHP for-loop in the HTML - edited my answer

Comment: Thanks, i can see this works however i get an error when using it with the  output from shell_exec: PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 1 in /var/www/html/user1/examples/test1.php on line 6
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() /var/www/html/user1/examples/test1.php:0
Array
(
    [000000000] => 
)
<html>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Animal</th>
    <th>Number</th>
  </tr>
<tr><td>000000000</td><td></td></tr></table>
</html>

Comment: Can you please verify `$res` contain my output before running the HTML code? (in the PHP section) - Define the array hard-coded as `$res = array("Cats" => "3", "Dogs" => "9", "Fish" => "2");` and see if it works

Comment: It doesn't, the problem seems to be with the output of shell_exec, when i run the command in the command line it outputs the desired values, but when i run it inside shell_exec i just receive one number, any ideas why?

Comment: @jonnyb notice **exec** return the output as array so you do not need the `explode` but if you using **shell_exec** it return as string - which you are using? (your example and comment are different...)

Comment: I am using shell_exec: i have used your code like this:                                    
`<?php
$str =  exec( "command" );
$arr = explode(PHP_EOL, $str); //break each line
$arr = array_chunk($arr,2); // group each pair
foreach($arr as $e)
    $res[$e[0]] = $e[1]; // group each pair as key and value
print_r($res);
?> `

however i receive this error: `PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 1 in /var/www/html/user1/examples/test1.php on line 7
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() /var/www/html/user1/examples/test1.php:0
Array
(
    [3] => 
)`

Comment: Could you please share the contain of `$str` and `$arr` after the `explode`. You probably need to filter `null` or `\n` from your array

Comment: after explode, $str = 3 ,  when i echo $arr i get : 'PHP Notice:  Array to string conversion in /var/www/html/user1/examples/test1.php on line 6
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() /var/www/html/user1/examples/test1.php:0
'

Comment: So you better check you "commad" output. And you cannot `echo` array - use `var_dump`

Comment: My command works in the command line it is just: cat 1.txt  | awk '{print $1}'

Comment: I fixed it by changing exec to shell_exec ..  Thankyou!

Answer (score 0):

You could use the preg_split() function to split the string along linebreaks into an array, and loop through the array two at a time, shifting the first two off at every loop.

```
<table>
<?php
$Output = <<< EOF
Cats
3
Dogs
9
Fish
2
EOF;

$animals = preg_split('/[\n\r]+/', trim($Output));

while (!empty($animals)) {
    echo "<tr>\n";
    echo "<td>{$animals[0]}</td>\n";
    echo "<td>{$animals[1]}</td>\n";
    echo "</tr>\n";
    array_shift($animals);
    array_shift($animals);
}
?>
</table>
```

Comment: I am receiving the following error: trim() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in /test.php on line 4

Comment: I see. I expected $Output to be a string, but I suppose it is an array, when you use the exec() function. If you'd use the function shell_exec(), as you said under dWinder's answer, it should work.